# open problems in mathematical finance

Tags: stochastic-processes, research, probability

What are open problems in mathematical finance that use fundamental concepts of mathematics (functional analysis, geometry and topology, algebra and number theory etc.) and not data-driven.

I have read online and some answers include:

**Stefan's problem for American Options**

**The lack of an analog of Clark-Haussmann formula in deterministic calculus**

**Explicit formulas for replicating strategies**

among others. Could you suggest some really nice mathematical (and not statistical) ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better served on math stack exchange.

Comment: Hi Xen92, welcome to Quant SE. Your question would be better served on the math stack exchange site.

Comment: OK, @AfterWorkGuinness, I get you right! Thanks for that.

Comment: Np. A mod will move your question

Comment: I think it fits better here. Mathematical Finance is definitely in scope here. The question doesn't fit that well in the Q&A format though. I'm not aware of an existing Open Problems question so I made this one community wiki.

Comment: I think we can keep the question here

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to address interesting problems that are interesting for financial mathematics, I do not believe you have the good list.

**Pricing.**
For instance, most of explicit formulas for pricing that are not available yet will never be. In this direction, you should have a look at **simulation techniques**. See for instance [Nonlinear Option Pricing](https://books.google.fr/books?id=sIfNBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA431&ots=i6TZ-wp7-b&dq=monte%20carlo%20particles%20simulation%20non%20linear%20finance%20touzi&hl=fr&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false). Interesting convergences remains to be proved.

**Stochastic Calculus.** 
In terms of extending the reach of stochastic calculus (like Malliavin did some years ago), you can have a look at the **Ito-Tanaka Trick** and its extensions. It gives deep clues about the regularity of stochastic functions. See for instance [Stochastic regularization effects of semi-martingales on random functions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05579).

**Mean-Field Games.**
It you like PDE and / or probabilities, you should definitely read papers on MFG. They are great. Then have been mainly introduced by two great mathematicians (PL Lions and JM Lasry). See their seminal [Mean Filed Game](http://www.math.uni-muenster.de/u/burger/teaching/seminarkollektiv/lasrylions.pdf) paper. If you want to read a "simple" paper (restricted on 1st orders PDE), have a look at [Mean field games systems of first order](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.1789). 
For a probabilistic viewpoint, see [Probabilistic Analysis of Mean-Field Games](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5780).

**Optimal Transport.**
For BSDE and transport big fans, *martingale transport* is your topic. Have a look at [Complete Duality for Martingale Optimal Transport on the Line](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.00671). [Nizar Touzi](http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Touzi_N/0/1/0/all/0/1) wrote a lot of papers in the area.

**Transaction Costs.**
Solving investment problems with transaction costs give birth to interesting situations. It is the less generic topic of my list, but I like it a lot. The bibliography of [Asymptotic Lower Bounds for Optimal Tracking: a Linear Programming Approach](http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04295) will give you an good overview of papers.

*More Details.*
If you want to find yourself interesting topics, you can have a look at the program of the [Louis Bachelier seminar](https://sites.google.com/site/seminairebachelierparis/programme-2015-2016) (a reference in math finance for reasearchers).